# Directive with a dynamic template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have a directive that take a model and print all model's elements with an `ng-repeat`. Something like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myDirective', [])
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

    function myDirective() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                mlModel: '=',
            },
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="actor in mlModel">{{actor.code}} - {{actor.name}}</li></ul>'
        };
    }
})();
```

Somewhere else I have the model:

```
vm.testModel = [{
  'code' : 'ABC',
  'name' : 'A name'
}, {
  'code' : 'DCE',
  'name' : 'Another nane'
}];
```

and the directive is used in this way:

```
<my-directive ml-model="vm.testModel"></my-directive>
```

This works pretty well and I have a [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/YqZQc9LMBSkiKrSTm39k?p=preview) as demo. This directive should be used in more than one place with slightly different model, for example I should have a model like this:

```
vm.testModel2 = [{
  'id' : '34234',
  'description' : 'A description'
}, {
  'id' : '456345',
  'description' : 'This is another description'
}];
```

The structure is the same, but now `code` property is called `id`, and `name` property is called `description`. Small difference that cause *huge* problem since inside the directive I have hard coded how to read the model (i.e. I wrote `{{actor.code}} - {{actor.name}}`).

I would send the code for model reading as a directive parameter and use it inside the directive's template. Something like:

```
<my-directive ml-model="vm.testModel" ml-parser="{{actor.code}} - {{actor.name}}"></my-directive>
<my-directive ml-model="vm.testModel2" ml-parser="{{actor.id}} - {{actor.description}}"></my-directive>
```

Is this possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in the `compile` attribute from the directive, so add:

```
compile:function(element,attrs){
    element.find('li').append(attrs.mlParser);
}
```

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/DE4ESpV83rC7HvNHb35z?p=preview) example.

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly changed the directive code, take a look:

```
function myDirective() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                mlModel: '=',
            },
            link : function(scope, element, attrs){
              scope.view = [];

              scope.mlModel.forEach(function(actor){
                scope.view.push({name : actor[Object.keys(actor)[0]], value : actor[Object.keys(actor)[1]]});
              });
            },
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="actor in view">{{actor.name}} - {{actor.value}}</li></ul>'
        };
    }
```

Comment: This will resolve *this* problem, but is too fragile in the wild :)